# PHP MySQL QUERY with Negative Double values

Tags: php, mysql, double

I have a table in my database that stores decimal coordinates which I'm trying to query using PHP and MySQL.

The problem I have is when I'm trying to retrieve rows that have negative values.

I'm testing in a web browser with an url in the format: https://example.com/coordinates.php?latfrom=51.725265&latto=51.825265&lonfrom=-1.385438&lonto=-1.285438

The JSON output is as expected with the **latitude** but the **longitude** retrieves all rows regardless of whether they fall outside of the **where clause**.

```
<?php
$latFrom = $_GET['latfrom'];
$latTo = $_GET['latto'];
$lonFrom = $_GET['lonfrom'];
$lonTo = $_GET['lonto'];
$connection = db_connect();
if ($connection->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} else {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM coordinates WHERE (`longitude` BETWEEN '" . $lonFrom . "' AND '" . $lonTo . "') AND (`latitude` BETWEEN '".$latFrom."' AND '".$latTo."')";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
    if (!$result) {
        printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($connection));
        exit();
    } else {
        $rows1 = array();
        while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            $rows[] = $r;
    }
}

function filter_val($val){
    $val = array_map('utf8_encode', $val);
    return $val;
}
    $rows = array_map('filter_val', $rows);

    mysqli_close($connection);
    print json_encode($rows);
}
```

If I run the query with phpMyAdmin I get the desired result. The following query works fine:

```
SELECT * FROM coordinates WHERE (`longitude` BETWEEN '-1.385438' AND '-1.285438') AND (`latitude` BETWEEN '51.725265' AND '51.825265');
```

I'm under the impression that the lowest negative value has to be the first value in the WHERE clause. I've tried every which way to get the query to work in php. I also believe that Floats/Doubles are stored as Strings in MySQL so I've tried casting the values into Floats.

I'm missing something but cannot work out what it is.

Thanks

Comment: Oh dear, after reading through the question I've realised I'd made a typo on one of the parameters in the url. I believe the code which I've now edited, is working code so may be of help to someone else. Apologies if you've spent any time looking at this. (Spent all day on this!).

Comment: in the phpMyAdmin query, it looks like you've swapped the values of lonFrom and lonTo... the order of the arguments in MySQL BETWEEN makes a difference "`foo BETWEEN 2 AND 42`" is significantly different from "`foo BETWEEN 42 AND 2`". The pattern in this code is vulnerable to SQL Injection... potentially unsafe values must either be supplied as bind placeholders in a prepared statement, or if that's not possible, then by properly escaping by way of custom built function `mysqli_real_escape_string`

Comment: @spencer7593, thanks for looking at this. I changed values for the purpose of the question but couldn't even seem to get that right. I believe the edited code should now work. Apologies if you spent too much time on it.

Comment: If the phpMyAdmin query is returning expected results, we surmise that the datatype of the `latitude` and `longitude` columns must be numeric and not character. (String comparisons would potentially different results. Consider e.g. `SELECT '-11.0' BETWEEN '-1.2' AND '-2.3'` returns 1.  My preference would be to make it explicit we are meaning to compare numeric values,  `'-11.0'+0  BETWEEN '-2.3'+0 AND '-1.2'+0`

Comment: Obligatory comment about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound queries

Comment: @Strawberry, good point. The api I'm using is private and accessed with an api key. I will definitely look at strengthening the security with regards to your comment, thanks.

Comment: Good. There's really no excuse not to use them!